# How to reveal a DIV during HOVER on another DIV?

Tags: jquery, hover, onmouseover

I know there are multiple variations of this scenario but I've struggled making it work.

I'm attempting something very close to yellowpages.com Just do a search for pizza, or anything for that matter to get the results to populate.

Notice how a "DIV" is revealed on the hover of each individual element? The actions at the bottom of each listing? I need to do this. I have a very similar project that I'm working on that creates listings based off of database content.

The best way to explain would be if I were able to change the z-index of the "footer" when hovering over the main container of the entire listing.

This is my first post on this site.. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hi did any of the solutions worked for you?

Comment: Yes, and I'm very sorry for such a delay in response. Thank you very much for your help. I was able to use your example to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly easy to do this in jQuery. To show or hide a div you can use:

```
$(".moreInfoDiv").show();
$(".moreInfoDiv").hide();
```

Of course assuming that you have defined your divs already

```
<div class="div1">
<div class="moreInfoDiv">
```

So your final code show look something like this

```
$('.div1').hover(
    function() {
       $(".moreInfoDiv").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(".moreInfoDiv").hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
$(function(){
  $('#div1').hover(function(){
    $('#div2').css('z-index', '10');
  }, function(){
    $('#div2').css('z-index', '0');  
  });       
});
```

Here's an example of a [Working jsFiddle showing z-index changes on hover.](http://jsfiddle.net/gsQeu/)